# Ocaml read list from file

Tags: list, ocaml

I need to take list of list of integers from file and use my func combine to it. See please on my code, where is my mistake?

```
# let f x l = List.filter ((<>) x) l 
  let rec comb = function  
  | [] -> []
  | x::[] -> [[x]]
  | l -> 
    List.fold_left (fun acc x -> acc @ List.map (fun p -> x::p) ( comb ( f x l))) [ ] l  ;;

let file = "example.dat"
  let message = [[1;2];[3;4]] 
  let () =      
    let oc = open_out file in
    fprintf oc "%s\n" message;
    close_out oc;
    let ic = open_in file in
    try 
      let line = input_line ic in    
    print_endline line;
    flush stdout;
    close_in ic
    with e ->
    close_in_noerr ic;
    raise e;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation fails here : `fprintf oc "%s\n" message;`  because `%s` expects a string whereas `message` is of type  `int list list`.

You have to iterate fprintf accross the list :

```
 List.iter (fun l -> 
        List.iter (fun i -> fprintf oc "%d ") l)  message;
```

The complete code :

```
  let file = "example.dat"
  let message = [[1;2];[3;4]] 
  let () =      
    let oc = open_out file in
    List.iter (fun l -> List.iter (fun x -> fprintf oc "%d\n" x) l) message ;
    close_out oc;
    let ic = open_in file in
    try 
      let line = input_line ic in    
    print_endline line;
    flush stdout;
    close_in ic
    with e ->
    close_in_noerr ic;
    raise e;;
```

Comment: In this case I have an Error: 
"This expression has type int -> unit
  but an expression was expected of type unit"

Comment: Yes, it works! But, tell me please, how can I use my function comb with list of lists, which I got from file?

Comment: what is the purpose of this function ? Is this question an exercise assignment ??

Comment: looks like comb returns all possible permutations of a given list.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Comb works right, it takes list of lists and returns list of transmutation. But now I need to get this list of lists from file.